# Receiving error when attempting to setup python within GIT Bash

Tags: python, git, anaconda, git-bash

I attempted to follow the instructions from this link https://prishitakapoor2.medium.com/configuring-git-bash-to-run-python-for-windows-a624aa4ae2c5 to setup python with git bash. However when I attempt to run source .bashrc I receive the following error

bash: export: `python.exe export PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Grant/bin:/c/Program Files/Oculus/Support/oculus-runtime:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin:/cmd:/c/Udacity/Python:/c/Udacity/Python/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/c/Udacity/Python/Library/usr/bin:/c/Udacity/Python/Library/bin:/c/Udacity/Python/Scripts:/c/Users/Grant/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin:/c/Users/Grant/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/c/Users/Grant/Anaconda3:/c/Users/Grant/Anaconda3/scripts alias python=winpty:/c/users/grant/anaconda3:/c/users/grant/anaconda3/Scripts:\C\Users\Grant\anaconda3:\C\Users\Grant\anaconda3/Scripts:\C\Users\Grant\Desktop\anaconda3:\C\Users\Grant\Desktop\anaconda3\Scripts:/c/Users/Grant/Anaconda3:/c/Users/Grant/Anaconda3/scripts': not a valid identifier bash: .bashrc: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching` "'

I have attempted to uninstall both batch and anaconda and reinstall both to fix the issue but I am unable to resolve the problem. Any tips? I am very new to this and trying to get python setup on my local PC for the first time.

I attempted to update the path by using the echo 'export PATH="$PATH:[YOUR_PATH]:[YOUR_PATH]/Scripts"' >> .bashrc again but this did not allow me to change the path and I am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As error tells, you have unmatched `"` in your .bashrc file. To more accurate answer,will be good if you attach .bashrc file